# How to allow custom HTML tags and JavaScript in content in CKEditor5?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

Looks like, `CKEditor 5` is doing some `sanitization`, so custom tags and the `Javascript` code getting delete from the content.
What configuration is needed to allow `custom html tags` and java script code in `CKEditor5` ?

Below is the my `React component`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const HTMLEditor = ({ setHtml, content }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data={content}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          setHtml(editor.getData());
        }}
        config={ {
          toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ],
          allowedContent: true,
          extraAllowedContent: '*(*);*{*}'
        } }
        onInit={editor => {
          console.log(editor);
          debugger;
          editor.config.allowedContent = true;
          editor.config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*)';
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HTMLEditor;
```

I tried adding the below config but that doesn't seem to work:

```
config={ {
          toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ],
          allowedContent: true,
          extraAllowedContent: '*(*);*{*}'
        } }
```

Below are the dependencies:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^37.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.0.0",
```

Comment: Create your own branch/fork of that library/code?

Comment: Please give me a reference, how I can do that.

Comment: You would have to contact the owners of that code to see if they even offer that - or have another option for you.  https://ckeditor.com/